# Mysql retrieve columns as rows

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, rows

I have two mysql tables health_status_questions and health_answers. Helow is the image.

[health_status_questions table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Lfg.png)

And here the haelth_answers table

[health_answers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Wjz.png)

And finally, I need to retrieve rows like below by combining both tables.

[equired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4xR6.png)

Comment: Someone please help..

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT qs.id, qs.QstnShort, qs.QstnDetail, 
q1.Q1, q2.Q2, q3.Q3, q4.Q4, q5.Q5, q6.Q6, 
q7.Q7, q8.Q8, q9.Q9, q10.Q10, q11.Q11, q12.Q12,
q13.Q13, q14.Q14, q15.Q15, q16.Q16, q17.Q17,
q18.Q18, q19.Q19, q20.Q20
FROM health_status_questions qs, health_answers q1,
health_answers q2, health_answers q3, health_answers q4, 
health_answers q5, health_answers q6, health_answers q7,
health_answers q8, health_answers q9, health_answers q10,
health_answers q11, health_answers q12, health_answers q13,
health_answers q14, health_answers q15, health_answers q16,
health_answers q17, health_answers q18, health_answers q19
health_answers q20
WHERE q1.id = 1 and q2.id = 1 and q3.id = 1 and q4.id 
and q5.id = 1 and q6.id = 1 and q7.id = 1 and q8.id
and q9.id = 1 and q10.id = 1 and q11.id = 1 and q12.id
and q13.id = 1 and q14.id = 1 and q15.id = 1 and q16.id
and q17.id = 1 and q18.id = 1 and q19.id = 1 and q20.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Having one column per answer is really bad design, as you no doubt have noticed. A good sing of something being wrong with your schema is that you need to add a column to add a question. With a proper design you would just do an INSERT.

Anyway, you want to turn these columns into lines, so the answer would look like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS qid, Q1 AS qv FROM health_answers WHERE id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS qid, Q2 FROM health_answers WHERE id=1
UNION ALL
...yadda yadda...
UNION ALL
SELECT 20 AS qid, Q20 FROM health_answers WHERE id=1
```

This will turn your 20 columns into 20 lines, each with a "qid" equal to the number of the column, and a "qv" equal to the content of the column.

Next you can join this to get the presentation you want:

```
SELECT q.*, qa.qv
FROM (huge SELECT with the unions above) qa
JOIN health_status_questions q ON (q.id=qa.qid)
```

But if you can still change it to a link table with one line per question and answer, something like (session_id, question_id, answer_id) please do it ASAP, you will save on headaches down the road...

**Edit: a better schema**

It's rather simple. You'd have a table for questions:

```
questions
question_id, question_text, ...
```

You can add a "question_type" column to determine if the the answers should be numerical (age, weight) or yes/no, stuff like that.

Now to record the answers of each session:

```
answers_sessions:
session_id, question_id, answer
```

When the user starts the questionnaire they will get a session_id. Then for every question they answer, insert a line with the id of the question and the answer.

If all questions are yes/no or numerical then answer would just be an INT. If all questions are multiple choice then it would be the id of the answer from a table answers.

So, after the user answers the 20 questions you get 20 lines in answers_sessions table, and to get the display you want all you have to do is JOIN this to questions to get the question text.

Adding new questions simply requires an insert into questions table, which is a lot simpler than modifying the code and database structure.

Note: You would need a separate answers table for more detailed questions which require multiple choice answers.

```
answers:
question_id (FK), answer_id (PK), answer_text, answer order maybe too
```

For example a question "what is your favorite color" would have lines in the answers table with "red" "green" etc. Having the answers in a table makes it easy to add/remove/update and join with it for display purposes. But your questions all seem to be yes/no so you will not need this.

Comment: Tell me a proper db design to get this result. Thank u for ur response.

Comment: ok, what are fields id and donor_id in health_answers table ? I'm looking at something like a session id, which identifies one user answering the questionnaire, and thus identifies all this user's answer for this session.

Comment: Exactly u said it.

Comment: My app will ask 20 health related questions to the signed in user. When user answering the db should be updated and other user can see this answes.

Comment: Let me implement this. I will let u know the result. Thank u so much brother.

Comment: will you please show me the code example and table structure.